# Равномерное распределение картинок и текста горизонтально

Tags: изображения, текст, разметка

имеются три столбца с текстом, над каждым из которых нужно по центру поместить картинку. Все это затем нужно распределить равномерно по горизонтали. Текст я распределил, а вот как ещё к нему привязать картинки не знаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно обернуть текст и картинки в общие блоки и потом уже блоки выровнять по горизонтали.

Например

```
<div  class="container">
   <div class="block">
      <img src="some_img.jpg">
      <p>Text</p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
      <img src="some_img.jpg">
      <p>Text</p>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
      <img src="some_img.jpg">
      <p>Text</p>
   </div>
</div>

<style>
   .container {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
   }
   .block {
     width: 27%;
     text-align: center;
   }
   .block p {
     text-align: left;
   }
</style>
```